# More than one Möbius transformation connecting two sets of 3 points on Riemann sphere?

Tags: mobius-transformation

$SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ transformations, or Möbius transformations as they are called, are an isometry of the Riemann sphere. This means that under these transformations the Riemann sphere is mapped onto itself. In particular, there should be exactly one Möbius transformation that takes a set of 3 points $z_1,z_2,z_3$ and maps them to a set of any other 3 points $\tilde z_1,\tilde z_2,\tilde z_3$ on the sphere (in complex coordinates):

$$\tilde z_1=\frac{a z_1+b}{c z_1+d}~~,~~\tilde z_2=\frac{a z_2+b}{c z_2+d}~~,~~\tilde z_3=\frac{a z_3+b}{c z_3+d}~~,~~a d-b c=1$$

Let's say we choose for example:

$$z_1=1~~,~~z_2=2~~,~~z_3=3$$

and search for the explicit transformation that takes these points to their negatives:

$$\tilde z_1=-1~~,~~\tilde z_2=-2~~,~~\tilde z_3=-3$$

Then we quickly realize that there are not one but two distinct transformations that accomplish this:

$$a=-i,b=0,c=0,d=i~~~\text{ or }~~~a=i,b=0,c=0,d=-i$$

What is going on here? Is the statement that a transformation taking 3 points to any other 3 is unique wrong? Or maybe I made a mistake in setting up the equations and introduced a degeneracy of some sort?

PS:

Even the identity operation does not seem to be unique, since trying to take the points $z_1=1~~,~~z_2=2~~,~~z_3=3$ into $\tilde z_1=1~~,~~\tilde z_2=2~~,~~\tilde z_3=3$ can be accomplished by

$$a=-1,b=0,c=0,d=-1~~~\text{ or }~~~a=1,b=0,c=0,d=1$$

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Note that the coefficients are only determined up to a scalar multiple, since a Mobius transformation is a fraction.

Comment: @jgon Actually down to a square root of unity factor because of the condition $ad-bc=1\,$. OP's question is the case where the factor is $-1$.

Comment: Oh right, sorry didn't see that this was PSL not PGL.

Comment: @dxiv Is there a representation for these transformations which does not have such multiplicity? For instance, if we want to calculate the volume of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ we might want to integrate over all $a,b,c,d$ for which $ad-bc=1$, but then we'd have to remove regions related by a square root of unity factor, which is kind of annoying. Is there a representation without redundancies?

Comment: @Kagaratsch Guess you could limit $a$ to some half-plane such as $\operatorname{Re}(a) \ge 0\,$.

Comment: @dxiv but if $\Re(a)\geq 0$, what to do in the first example, where $a=\pm i$ in the two different ways to express the transformation? Perhaps one should take $\Im(a)\geq 0$ as well?

Comment: @Kagaratsch That only happens on the imaginary axis which is of measure $0$ and shouldn't affect the integral.

Comment: @dxiv thank you! That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **transformations** represented by these quadruples of numbers are identical functions. The *representations* happen to be different.

It's a little like the way that "The guy whose office is #365" and "John Hughes" are different descriptions, but refer to the same person.

Theorems and definitions are tricky things: you have to read every single word.

Comment: I wonder if there is a representation for these transformations which does not have such multiplicity? For instance, if we want to calculate the volume of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ we might want to integrate over all $a,b,c,d$ for which $ad-bc=1$, but then we'd have to remove regions related by a square root of unity factor, which is kind of annoying. Is there a representation without redundancies?